# How to saved wordpress user register time in est format?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

i am working on my wordpress project when someone create an account on my site user register time store in UTC timezone when i am changed timezone setting in wordpress and set new york only my post store new york time my  user register time still in Utc timezone but i want when someone register on my site the time is store in EST How i can do this
Thanks in Advance

if anyone have any idea let me know its very help ful for me thanks

Comment: I think I'd personally recommend just converting to a specific time zone when needed, however you can use the [`wp_pre_insert_user_data`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_pre_insert_user_data/) hook to update the `user_registered ` key accordingly. Also, EST only runs for half the year, then EDT kicks in. You might want to consider ET instead.